# Highlight area with backgroundcolor fadein/fadeout

Tags: javascript, jquery

Hi I'd like to highlight `.small`. Do not have access to add jQuery UI e.g. can't use `.animate`.

**HTML**

```
<span class="small">10 left</span>
```

**jQuery**

```
$(".small").css("background-color","orange");
```

**Question**: How do I add background-color orange and make it `.fadeOut()` here? This below doesn't work? Only want to fadeout the background color, nothing else.

```
$(".small").css("background-color","orange").fadeOut();
```

Comment: so you want on page load. the span to have bck orange. and then the span to fade out ? or just it's background color

Comment: @MihaiT just bg color

Comment: why don't just use css animations for that ?

Comment: something like this you want $(".small").css("background-color","orange").fadeOut(2000); ?

Comment: @shubhamkhandelwal yes but not fade out the .small content, only the backgroundcolor

Answer (score 6, accepted):

you can use CSS animations to do that

see snippet below

```css
span {
  background-color:orange;
  animation-name:bckanim;
  animation-fill-mode:forwards;
  animation-duration:3s;
  animation-delay:0s;
}
@keyframes bckanim {
  0% {background-color:orange;}
  100% { background-color:transparent;}
}
```

```html
<span class="small">10 left</span>
```

Answer (score 1):

You can use timeouts and css transitions nicely for this.

For more information about transitions: 
https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/CSS_Transitions/Using_CSS_transitions

```js
$(document).ready(function(){
   var $block = $('.block');
  /** first timeout to make the document do its stuff before this thing runs **/
  window.setTimeout(function() {
  $block.addClass('orange-fade');
     /** second timeout to turn it back to normal **/
     window.setTimeout(function() {
         $block.removeClass('orange-fade');
      },2000);
    
    },1000);
  
  });
```

```css
.block {
  display:block;
  width:200px;
  height:200px;
  background-color:green;
  /** Transitions to give a nice effect **/
  -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
}

.orange-fade {
     background-color: #AD310B;
     -webkit-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -moz-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -o-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     -ms-transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
     transition: background-color 1000ms linear;
  }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class=" block transition">
   Look at me! Look at you! now look back to me! i'm on a horse!
</div>
```

Comment: why so much code for a simple question ? why using other html structure and not the one the OP posted?

Comment: Because I don't know what else he might want to do with it, and when he wants to run it. after document.ready? whilst document.ready? when the user scrolls to it? does he need more javascript? The boundaries were loose, so i gave an answer that gives maximum flexiblity to modify, to insert more css/javascript at points.

Answer (score 0):

You can do something like this with css transitions on a class and then add or remove the class with JS.

HTML:

```
<span class="small">10 left</span>
```

CSS:

```
.small {
  background-color: #fff;
  transition-property: background-color;
  transition-duration: 1s;
  transition-delay: 1s;
}

.orange {
  background-color: orange;
}
```

JS:

```
$(".small").addClass("orange");
```

DEMO  https://jsfiddle.net/ry5qxvos/

Comment: hmm i like this a lot though

Comment: how do I remove the background color too?

Comment: just add a class that has a transparent background color (or whatever color you want) DEMO  https://jsfiddle.net/Ltgo05ut/1/

Answer (score 0):

try this  http://jsfiddle.net/x2jrU/92/ use this jquery to make background color of ur wish with fadein/fadeout option.

```js
jQuery.fn.highlight = function() {
    $(this).each(function() {
        var el = $(this);
        el.before("<div/>")
        el.prev()
            .width(el.width())
            .height(el.height())
            .css({
                "position": "absolute",
                "background-color": "#ffff99",
                "opacity": ".9"   
            })
            .fadeOut(500);
    });
}
    
$("#target").highlight();
```

```css
#target { width: 300px; height: 100px; border: 1px solid red; }
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div id="target">Highlight Me</div>
```

Comment: width ? height ? position:absolute ? what's this ? :)

Comment: width n height of the div.. check out the fiddle link :)

Comment: but why use this ? the op's question had a simple html structure. no need to overcomplicate things and change the HTML and CSS of the ops code entirely